# GET URI from webserver by IP address not matching hostname's IP

Tags: curl, http

Using `curl`, I would like to request a URI from a web server via a specific IP address that does not necessarily match the forward DNS of the hostname.

For example, suppose the hostname www.example.com would normally resolve to 192.0.2.222. How would I make `curl` request the URI `http://www.example.com` from 192.0.2.111 instead (and see the response)?

Note: I would like to avoid using `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The `--resolve` option for `curl` does what you want:

### `--resolve <host:port:address>`

> Provide a custom address for a specific host  and  port  pair.
>                 Using  this, you can make the curl requests(s) use a specified
>                 address and prevent the otherwise normally resolved address to
>                 be used. Consider it a sort of /etc/hosts alternative provided
>                 on the command line. The port number should be the number used
>                 for  the specific protocol the host will be used for. It means
>                 you need several entries if you want to  provide  address  for
>                 the same host but different ports.
>
> This  option  can be used many times to add many host names to
>                 resolve.
>
> (Added in 7.21.3)

### Example

Request `/foo` from `192.0.2.111` as `www.example.com`. (Requests for `www.example.com` on port 80 are mapped to `192.0.2.111` by `curl`.)

`curl --resolve www.example.com:80:192.0.2.111 http://www.example.com/foo`